# msysgit and msbuild path disagreement

Tags: bash, msbuild, msysgit

When executing msbuild from an msysgit bash prompt, I have been running into some 9009 errors for targets that have commands that are in the path. By adding an execution of `echo $(Path)` to the failing target, it becomes evident that msbuild isn't able to interpret the path anymore.

Since msbuild is launched from an msysgit bash shell, it has a bash-style `$PATH` variable (e.g., `/c/Directory1:/c/Directory2`), but it seems that it is trying to interpret the value as a DOS-style `%PATH%` (e.g., `c:\Directory1;c:\Directory2`). Obviously, that fails.

Is there an elegant way to correct this behavior? I suppose I could make an alias that will convert the path and inject it with `-p:Path="..."`, but I thought it would be worth asking if there was a cleaner way before I embark on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a much easier answer: just don't have anything in the path using `~`, and msbuild does just fine with the sh-style path.

---

A script accomplishing the path fix that isn't too ugly, except for the munging of the path:

```
#/bin/sh
dospath=`echo ${PATH} | 
    sed "s-\(^\|:\)~\([/:]\|$\)-\1${HOME}\2-g" | 
    sed 's-:-;-g' | 
    sed 's-\(^\|;\)/\([A-Za-z]\)\([/;]\|$\)-\1\2:\3-g' | 
    sed 's-/-\\\\-g'`
msbuild=`which msbuild.exe`
whichresult=$?
if [ ${whichresult} -eq 0 ]; then
    PATH=${dospath}
    ${msbuild} $@
else
    echo 'msbuild.exe not found'
    exit ${whichresult}
fi
```